# Show that $p_{k}≥2k-1$ for all $k≥2$

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $p_{k}$ be the $k^{th}$ prime. Show that $p_{k}≥2k-1$ for all $k≥2$. This inequality is true for several values of $k$. For example $p_{2}=3≥2(2)-1=3$ and $p_{3}=5≥2(3)-1=5$.

Comment: [PNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) or are you looking for a simpler solution?

Comment: @rtybase: A simpler solution.

Comment: Induction? $p_k\geq 2k-1 \Rightarrow p_{k+1}\geq p_k+2\geq 2(k+1)-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: No even positive integers are prime except for $2$. Alternatively, as [rtybase](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/22583/rtybase)'s comment suggested, you can also use mathematical induction.